# What can one do with cross-sectional relationships?

Tags: time-series, trading, factor-models, research, data-mining

This is somewhat of a broad question, but I think we all would like to find signals that predict something in the future.  However, often times, we are just left with cross-sectional relationships (both variables go up in the same time frame, but lagged terms cannot predict each other).

- What are some things we can do, if we stumble upon a new cross-sectional relationship?
- Originally, I am hoping to find signals for things...can a cross-sectional relationship be turned into a signal or strategy of some sort?  Like a signal for entry or exit even though it itself offers no predictability.
- Could it be used in a similar way like the Factor models where there is no predictability and it's all about some sort of compensation for risk?  If so, what's a good resource to kinda get an understanding on how to convert a cross-sectional relationship into risk premium.

I'm looking for broad ideas or some examples on how correlation may be used in finance.  And basically next steps to go.

Thanks!